# Showing notification on page after redirect

Tags: javascript, php, forms, notifications

I'm having some trouble showing a notification on a page after redirect. I have a form  with action="ProcessForm.php" and on ProcessForm.php I redirect back to the page with the form using:

```
window.location = 'http://www.sample.php#success';
```

then on the sample.php page i created an if statement:

```
if(window.location.hash == 'http://www.sample.php#success')
{ echo"<div class="notification success">
    <span></span>
        <div class="text">
        <p><strong>Success!</strong>Form Submitted Successfully!</p>
        </div>
     </div>"
```

but when i'm redirected to that page there's no notification. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you really mixing JavaScript and PHP? It is not going to work and the server can not access the hash since it is not submitted with the request.

Comment: js with php must never be used for authentication or similar purpose as its a client-side scripting.

Comment: i'm totally new to this so I often make some mistakes

Answer (score 0):

echo is a php output function and is not valid in javascript. On top of this, window.location.hash is only going to give you the # so it would be equal to "#success".

Try using `document.write(<<htmlhere>>);`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need a simple php solution:

**ProcessForm.php**

```
$notice = urlencode('<div class="notification success">
<span></span>
    <div class="text">
    <p><strong>Success!</strong>Form Submitted Successfully!</p>
    </div>
 </div>');

header('Location: form.php?notice='.$notice);
```

**form.php**

```
if( !empty($_GET['notice']) ){

echo $_GET['notice'];

}
```